# How to specify an array with constant content and length in jsonschema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'd like to specify in jsonschema that returned array is always same with same objects (order doesn't matter) for example:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Snoop Dogg"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Eminem"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "50 Cent"
    }
]
```

Is it possible? If it is how?
I've tried tuple validation  - but it's not perfect cause order matters there
Thanks in advance for replies!

Comment: To clarify, you want to make sure an array always includes specific objects, but they may be in any order?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a combination of `allOf` and `contains`:

```
{
  "allOf": [
    { "contains": { "const": [ ... list0 ... ] } },
    { "contains": { "const": [ ... list1 ... ] } },
    { "contains": { "const": [ ... list2 ... ] } }
  ]
}
```